# React native expo Android emulator is not rendering uri image

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have Android emulator rendering text successfully, however it is not rendering image with uri. Funny thing iOS simulator rendering both text and image. What could be the problem? should I add anything for Android? here is my code,

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={{
          width: 200,
          height: 300,
          uri: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
        }}
      />
      <Text> App</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the `style` prop to the styles and the `source` prop to the source of the image

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={{ width: 200, height: 300}}
        source={{uri: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'}}
      />
      <Text> App</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Well, i dont know why. But if you can get some logs maybe i can help you with that.

Comment: Or, if you're ok with that, just add as accepted answer please!